# Is it practical to use Google App Engine for a Django app?

Tags: mysql, django, google, google-app-engine, virtualenv

I'm currently building a Django app that uses a MySQL backend. Traditionally I've worked with a VirtualEnv where I can install python packages, set folder permissions, etc.

From some pages I've found through research, it makes it seem like Google App Engine was not really designed for something like Django. (Many things suggest using Django-nonrel, but I believe google now has Google Cloud SQL).

Here are my questions:

1) Does Google App Engine support a Django app that uses MySQL? (i.e. is Google Cloud SQL compatible with Django **natively**?)

2) Does Google let you install python packages in a VirtualEnv-ish way? If not, is there an alternative way of installing packages?

3) Do they have any restrictions that are worth noting compared to a service such as Linode?

Finally, I know this is really subjective, but would you recommend GAE for a Django project? I like the idea of Google's widespread servers and security. Data replication is always a good thing, I just want to make sure it is the right path to take. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes - here is explanation https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#django
2. Yes, on the development server. On Google Clound you don't need virtualenv.
3. Google App Engine is PaaS, so you have an access only to API not to operating system. You can forget about operating system, Google takes care about it.

If you like Django, so you can use it for GAE app - it is ok. I'm personally prefer simplicity of webapp2 or flask frameworks.
GAE it's not only data replication, main advantages of GAE is High Scalability and Fast Deployment (from idea to deploy working code) out of the box.